# How use filemtime with all link?

Tags: php, date, hyperlink, filemtime

I would like to know, how use "filemtime" with all link ?

Example :
- My PHP file for get is : http://mywebsite.org/getdate.php
- The link that I want to get the date is : http://thegoodwebsite.net/i/banp.gif

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in `http` wrapper doesn't support [`stat`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php) family of functionality, like `filemtime`. So: you can't.

HTTP protocol define a `Last-Modified` header field that you may use instead.
With CURL:

```
$curl = curl_init('http://thegoodwebsite.net/i/banp.gif');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);

if (false !== curl_exec($curl)) {
    $time = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_FILETIME);
    echo 'remote time of the retrieved document: ', $time;
}

curl_close($curl);
```

If you get -1 it might be unknown.

Comment: "HTTP protocol define a Last-Modified header field that you may use instead.". How use it ?

Comment: @Aymeric98, added an example